# Max number of to message to send your AWS SQS FIFO queue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I have 50K of AWS Lambda instance running at the same time, and all of them send a message to a SQS FIFO queue.

I wondering what's the max number of message I can send to SQS FIFO queue per second?

I can't find such information on the AWS documentation.

Comment: but i have a FIFO queue

Comment: I removed my comment because it looks like I was wrong and E.J. Brennan's answer below is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Amazon SQS queues can deliver very high throughput. Standard queues support a nearly unlimited number of transactions per second (TPS) per API action. By default, FIFO queues support up to 3,000 messages per second with batching. To request a limit increase, file a support request. FIFO queues support up to 300 messages per second (300 send, receive, or delete operations per second) without batching.

From: [Increasing Throughput using Horizontal Scaling and API Action Batching](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-batch-api-actions.html#sqs-throughput-horizontal-scaling-and-batching)